# square 3 bit input using two 3 bit adders and logic gates

Tags: digital-logic

I am trying to figure out how to make a circuit that squares a 3-bit input using 2 3-bit binary adders and logic gates. Could someone point me in the right direction on how to design this? Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

If you insist using pure logic gates to make a 3 bit binary squarer (even such a thing?), **HERE IT IS!**
[image: 3-bit binary squarer]

Comment: If this answers your question, make sure to tick it (underneath the vote counter). If it doesn't answer your question, add a comment under here.